# Higher order interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, interpolation

Let we have some points $(x_i,y_i),~i=1,2,...n,$ that are scattered on a $2D$ domain like square. And $u_h$ is the solution of a numerical method at these points. Now, if I want to construct a higher order interpolation of $u_h$ at these points, how can I do that? Should  I find $u_h^{new}$ with some more points and then use the value of $u_h^{new}$ at these points? Is there any higher order interpolation that can construct with the same points in MATLAB?
I could not use interp2.

Comment: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html

Comment: @Winther unfortunately, the webpage can not find, I tried several times, I will really appreciate you if   could  help  me about that.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `griddata` function is finding a surface. Here is a way to see how the fit works.

**Problem statement**

The data is a sequence of $m$ points of the form $$\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k}, z_{k}
\right\}_{k=1}^{m}$$

The model surface is an approximation of order $d$. Consider $d=2$:
$$
 z(x,y) = a_{00} + a_{10}x + a_{01}y + a_{20}x^{2} + a_{11}xy + a_{02}y^{2}
$$

**Linear system**

$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A} a &= z \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
  1 & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1} y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m} & y_{m} & x_{m}^{2} & x_{m} y_{m} & y_{m}^{2} \\
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  a_{00} \\ a_{10} \\ a_{01} \\ a_{20} \\ a_{11} \\ a_{02}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  z_{1} \\ \vdots \\ z_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%%
\end{align}
%
$$

Note: the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is  a [Vandermonde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrix, the poster child for ill-conditioned matrices.

**Normal equations**

Forming the normal equations squares the condition number of the system. The solution here is for theoretical insight. If numerical problems manifest, investigate other methods like SVD or QR.

As $\mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, only the upper half is shown.

$$
%
\begin{align}
%
 \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} a &= \mathbf{A}^{*}z \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{llllll}
  m & \sum x & \sum y & \sum x^{2} & \sum xy & \sum y^{2} \\
    & \sum x^{2} & \sum yx & \sum x^{3} & \sum x^{2}y & \sum xy^{2} \\
    &  & \sum y^{2} & \sum x^{2}y & \sum xy^{2} & \sum y^{3} \\
    &  &  & \sum x^{3} & \sum x^{4}y & \sum x^{2}y^{2} \\
    &  &  &   & \sum x^{2}y^{2} & \sum xy^{3} \\
    &  &  &   &   & \sum y^{4} \\
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  a_{00} \\ a_{10} \\ a_{01} \\ a_{20} \\ a_{11} \\ a_{02}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{l}
  \sum z \\ \sum xz \\ \sum yz \\ \sum x^{2}z \\ \sum xyz \\ \sum y^{2}z
\end{array} \right]
%%
\end{align}
%
$$

**Normal equations solution**

$$
 a_{LS} = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*}\mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*}z
$$

**Increase degree of fit**

Increase $d$ from $2$ to $3$:
$$
 z(x,y) = a_{00} + a_{10}x + a_{01}y + a_{20}x^{2} + a_{11}xy + a_{02}y^{2}
 + a_{30}x^{3} + a_{21}x^{2}y + a_{12}xy^{2} + a_{03} y^{3}
$$
The new system matrix is has new columns
$$
\mathbf{A} =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccccccc|ccc}
  1 & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1} y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} & x_{1}^{3} & x_{1}^{2} y_{1} & x_{1}y_{1}^{2}  & y_{1}^{3} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m} & y_{m} & x_{m}^{2} & x_{m} y_{m} & y_{m}^{2} & x_{m}^{3} & x_{m}^{2} y_{m} & x_{m}y_{m}^{2}  & y_{m}^{3} \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
Algorithmically, increasing the fit order is a simple matter. Again, the numerics may present trouble.

Also, avoid the indeterminate form $0^{0}$. Force these terms to unity.